# Dual Boot - Cant Move files

Tags: dual-boot, permissions

I have a dual boot Win10 / Ubuntu 16.10. Until now, I was able to access the Windows partition through the Ubuntu file manager. I could move, copy, and paste files in Windows folders until now, when it suddenly only let me access the files. (I can read a document located in Windows, but there's no chance I can delete it, for example.)

Any ideas? It seems like a permission problem to me.
I think I can use gksu nautilus, but I don't want to have to go to the terminal every time I want to work with a file in Windows 10...

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you *certain* you can edit the files from sudo?  A frequent issue with Windows 10 is that the Windows partition gets hibernated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As you said, after checking sudo didnt do nothing, so win10 seems to be hibernated! Much Thanx for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Windows file system looks dirty to Ubuntu, so it gets mounted in readonly mode in Ubuntu. This is because Windows uses a hibernation file to save the system state.

You'll need to do this in Windows:

- open the Power control panel
- click on `change what the power buttons do`
- click on `change options that are unavailable`
- uncheck `fast start`
- close the Power control panel
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `powercfg /h off` *(turns off hibernation)*
- type `chkdsk /f c:` *(change c: to the correct drive letter, if required)*
- approve that chkdsk runs at next boot time
- reboot Windows

Rather than directly editing/deleting/etc files on your Windows partition, I'd recommend creating a shared NTFS partition on your hard disk that's accessible from both Windows and Ubuntu.